# Bootstrap Collapse worked with button fine, then, how to work with accordion-heading again?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, heading

Let me start with easy English:

I made a jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sangdth/DUsGu/

First, at step 1, click "*Go to step 2*" button.
Then, at step 2, click "*Go to step 3*" button.
At this place, **if my customer want to go back to step 1**, they click into the link "1. Register phone"

And you can see, the step 1 content show, but the step 3 content will not hide.
The same when they click on link "2. Choose Shape", both 1 and 3 content will not hide.

I have no idea how to make it work in both way, mean, Show/Hide with button is clicked, and the Heading also.

I had tried to replace `hide`, `show` with `toggle` but it did not work.

```
jQuery("#btn-phone").click(function() {
        $("#collapseOne").collapse('hide');
        $("#collapseTwo").collapse('show');
    });
```

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

P/S: I tried to search, but did not see. If my question is exist and had the answer, please let me know and I will delete my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following code:

```
 $('.accordion-toggle').on('shown', function () {
 $(this).addClass('active') });

$('.accordion-toggle').on('hidden', function () {
 $(this).removeClass('active') });
```

After the document ready function.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle for me? I tried but it can't work like I wish. Thank you.

Comment: Try out something mentioned in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665800/bootstrap-collapse-data-parent-not-working). Also take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7rTJ/2/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked great! I will take a deep look in your jsfiddle. Thank you again somuch.